# "Iterating" throw promises does not let to generate different ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Reading [some amazing tutorials](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) about promises, I've discovered that, if I need to interate throw some promises, I can't use forEach or some other "traditional" iteration mechanisms, I have to **use Q library for node, I've to "iterate" using `Q.all`.**

I've written a simple example in Nodejs Express in order to be sure I've understood promises:

```
var form = [
    {'name':'FORM_NAME_1.1',
     'label2':'FORM_LABEL_1.2'
    },
    {'name':'FORM_NAME_2.1',
     'label2':'FORM_LABEL_2.2'
    }
];
var params = ['params1','params2'];
var meta   = ['meta1','meta2'];

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
        return Q.all([
            form.map((currentValue,index,arr) => {
                req.id = Math.random();   //Random ID to be used in the next promises
                console.log(currentValue);
                return Form.insert(currentValue,req);
            }),
            params.map((currentValue,index,arr) => {
                console.log(req.id);
                return Field.insert(currentValue,req.id);
            }),
            meta.map((currentValue,index,arr) => {
                console.log(req.id);
                return Meta.insert(currentValue,req.id);
            })
        ])
    .catch((err) => next(err))
    .done(() => console.log('It\'s done'));
});
```

`Form.insert` code simply is a promise with a `console.log` call, the same for `Field.insert` and `Meta.insert`

```
var Form = {
    insert: (param1,req) => {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        console.log('Goes throw Form');
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

The problem is that seems to iterate right but **the dynamicly generated `id` does not change** along the promises, this is the console output:

```
Listening at port 3000...
{ name: 'FORM_NAME_1.1', label2: 'FORM_LABEL_1.2' }
Goes throw Form
{ name: 'FORM_NAME_2.1', label2: 'FORM_LABEL_2.2' }
Goes throw Form
0.3757301066790548
Goes throw Field
0.3757301066790548
Goes throw Field
0.3757301066790548
Goes throw Meta
0.3757301066790548
Goes throw Meta
It's done
```

Any ideas about what is going wrong? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason it is not working is because in first for loop, the `req.id` is set multiple times before other promises are started and and all of them end up using the last randomly generated value, change your code to:

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {

  let process = (currentValue,index,arr) => {
    let reqCopy = {id: Math.random()}
    for(let attr in req)   // copy all the request attributes
      if(attr && attr!='id')
        reqCopy[attr] = req[attr]
    return Q.all([
      Form.insert(form[index],reqCopy),
      Field.insert(params[index],reqCopy),
      Meta.insert(meta[index],reqCopy)
      ])
  }
  return Q.all(form.map(process))
    .catch(next)
    .done(() => console.log('It\'s done'));
})
```

you would notice that I am copying all the attributes of `req` to clone `reqCopy` for I am not sure what attributes of `req` are required by the subsequent methods, but at the same time, single `req.id` would not work thanks to the async nature of code

Comment: Thanks a lot mido! :D  I'm facing some other problems executing the first promise, I leave the url of the new thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456373/promises-stop-working-when-adding-a-insertion-query