# Promises stop working when adding a insertion query

Tags: node.js, promise, q

Asking about promises with Q library for node, mido helped me with a problem with the execution of promises [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432906/iterating-throw-promises-does-not-let-to-generate-different-ids/37433496#37433496). Basically, the solution was (almost) this code.

```
    var form= [
        {'name':'FORM_NAME_1.1',
         'label2':'FORM_LABEL_1.2'
        },
        {'name':'FORM_NAME_2.1',
         'label2':'FORM_LABEL_2.2'
        }
    ];
    var params = ['params1','params2'];
    var meta   = ['meta1','meta2'];

    let process = (currentValue,index,arr) => {
        //let reqCopy = {id: Math.random()}
        let reqCopy = {};
        for(let attr in req)  // copy all the request attributes 
            //if(attr && attr!='id')
                reqCopy[attr] = req[attr]
        return Q.all([
            Form.insert(connection,req,form[index],reqCopy),
            Field.insert(connection,req,params[index],reqCopy),
            Meta.insert(connection,req,meta[index],reqCopy)
        ])
    }
    return Q.all(form.map(process))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    .done(() => console.log('Done'));
```

But now I need to generate an id in the first promise **`(Form.insert)`** and pass it throw the others. It's easy to have the id of the inserted row using mySql library for Node. This is the promise form `Form`:

```
var Q = require('Q');

module.exports = {
    insert: (connection,req,dataToInsert,reqCopy) => {
        var deferred = Q.defer()
          , db       = 'DATABASE';

        console.log('Form.insert is executing with data: ' + JSON.stringify(dataToInsert));

    connection.query(`INSERT INTO ${db} SET ?`
        ,[dataToInsert]
        ,function(err, result) {
            if (err) deferred.reject(err);
            console.log('Result: ' + result.insertId);
            deferred.resolve(result.insertId); //Return id when data was inserted
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

But now, with the `INSERT INTO`query, the first promise is executed at the end of the process, doing it fails again:

```
//Promises are executed in the right order set in the .all array:
Form.insert is executing with data: {"name":"crf_NAME_1.1","label2":"FORM_LABEL_1.2"}
Field.insert is executing with data: "params1"
Meta.insert is executing with data: "meta1"
Form.insert is executing with data: {"name":"FORM_NAME_2.1","label2":"FORM_LABEL_2.2"}
Field.insert is executing with data: "params2"
Meta.insert is executing with data: "meta2"

//But Form.insert should generate the id before passing to the next promise.
C:\node\api\models\Form.js:17
            console.log('Result: ' + result.insertId); //IT FAILS, SHOULD BE EXECUTED BEFORE
```

I don't understain why this occurs because Form.insert is defined as a promise and return values (resolve and reject) are set after inserting the data, so flow should wait for its resolution.

Thanks!

Comment: you want Field.insert and Meta.insert to use Id from `Form.insert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass the `id` from first promise to others, you can do something like:

```
...
let process = (currentValue,index,arr) => {
  return Form.insert(connection,req,form[index]).then(id => Q.all([
    Field.insert(connection,req,params[index],id),
    Meta.insert(connection,req,meta[index],id)
  ]))
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `Q.all()` is useful if the operations are independent of each other.

If there *is* a dependency, you can use regular Promise chaining:

```
return Form .insert(connection,req,form[index],reqCopy)
            .then((insertId) => {
              return Q.all([
                Field.insert(connection, req, insertId, params[index], reqCopy), 
                Meta .insert(connection, req, insertId, meta[index], reqCopy)
              ])
            })
```

This assumes that `Field.insert()` and `Meta.insert()` are still independent of each other; if not, you can use the same trick to pass data from the former to the latter. I added `insertId` as extra argument to the insert methods as an example.